# Software test: verify if an ASCII output file contains or not a pattern according to a given input

Tags: c, string, automated-tests

I wish to test a software that receive commands, and produces ASCII logs. In particular I wish to check if this software is robust to irregular commands (e.g. outrange values, excessive number of parameters and so on). This is quite simple checking the logs, where should be present the echo of the accepted commands; moreover from the logs is possible to infer that the software have had the correct reaction. For ease the testing, we have developed batch scripts (we are on windows command-line) of the commands to be set.

My question is: exits a good and easy way to check the logs for the reaction at the given command?

The desired approach should be or a free testing suite or a scripting one, but easy and fast (we have not time to study a language such as ruby or perl). We have thought to batch files, but we are not persuaded that this is the best approach (e.g. most test should verify that a supposed string is ABSENT in logs).

Comment: I don't know if it would meet your needs, but you can do a lot with [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).  (And I believe there are versions for the various Windows command lines / shells).

Comment: I was thinking something similiar:  Using `findstr` and `errorlevel`.  But your post has very little detail on exactly what you want to do, so I can't be very precise.

Comment: @abelenky: The idea should be, if using batch: 1) in batch file set a good command -> a) verify that in the log is the echo of the command b) according to the command, verify that somewhere after the echo is present a given string, normally within a longer string. 2) in batch file set a wrong command: verify that in the logs there is not the echo, neither other "key" strings. Moreover these tests should be automatic ans the results (Fail/Pass) of these tests shou inserted in a report

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language that and read files and has regex should be sufficient.